# Removing one UploadedFile from a List<UploadedFile>

Tags: java, jsf

Well, I created a "action" in my ManagedBean to add pictures to a List, look my action bellow:

```
public void novaFoto(FileUploadEvent event) {
        uploadsFotos.add(event.getFile());
    }
```

Now, I must do the following: When users click a button ("Remove Picture") i must remove this picture from the List, But how can i get the UploadedFile if this is not a FileUploadEvent, is just a plain ActionEvent ?

My ideia is something like this (But how can i pass a FileUploadEvent if i will trigger this action with a commandButton):

```
public void removerFoto(FileUploadEvent event) {
        for(UploadedFile up : uploadsFotos){
            if (up.getFileName().equals(event.getFile().getFileName()))
                uploadsFotos.remove(up);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on how you want to present the list to the user.

If you use a datatable you can take the iteration var to process your delete action. Here is an example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{fileBean.files}" var="file" id="files">                        
      <h:column>
           <h:inputText value="#{file.name}"/>

           <h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{fileBean.delete(file)}">
                          <f:ajax render="@form"/>
           </h:commandButton>
      </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And this in your bean:

```
public void delete(UploadedFile file) {
        files.remove(file);
}
```